# Is there any restriction for writing property names C#

Tags: c#

I've written a class definition like

```
 public class Item
        {
            public double? 30dhi { get; set; }
            public double? 30dlo { get; set; }
            public double? 7dhi { get; set; }
            public double? 7dlo { get; set; }
        }
```

Why it's not allowing me to add properties having alphanumeric keys
The error is like below

> **invalid token '30d' for class , struct or interface member declaration**

Comment: you can write `_30dhi` instead

Comment: can someone explain me what is the point on downvotes ?

Comment: Use textual names like MonthHigh or WeekLow, or not so good in my eyes Lo7d, Hi30d

Comment: @holroy: "Month" and "30 day" aren't the same thing though. I agree the current names aren't good, but I wouldn't change "30 day" to "month".

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary: perhaps downvoters feel that a question the answer to which is in TFM, "does not show any research effort" (one of the explicit reasons stated for downvotes).

Comment: Note that the question of which this is a duplicate is specifically asking about class names, but the rules are the same as for property names; that question has an extensive discussion the rules for identifiers in C#, including at least two answers that are nearly identical in content to the one provided below.

Comment: @jonskeet, I know 30 days are not always a month, but in some contexts that is what it is used for...

Comment: @holroy: In *those* cases, I would agree - but why would you *assume* that the OP is using "30d" incorrectly, and suggest the change?

Comment: @jonskeet, I was merely indicating alternative names to avoid starting the names with numbers which your answer correctly states is illegal. Suggested MonthHigh to get OP thinking in a different way, but still credit him to choose proper names. And most, but not all,  times when I see 7 and 30 the context often is week and month.

Comment: @holroy: Well, I think that was somewhat misleading - it would have been more useful IMO to think of what the OP should use if they really *do* mean 30 days. `ThirtyDayHigh`? (I have the opposite experience to you - we always *do* mean 30 days rather than 1 month...)

Comment: @jonskeet,  point taken, will try to be clearer in the future

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why it's not allowing me to add properties having alphanumeric keys

A property name has to be an *identifier*. Identifiers in C# can't start with a digit. You can have a digit *after* the first character, but not *as* the first character.

See section 2.4.2 of the C# 5 specification for the precise details of what is allowed for an identifier. The full grammar is too long to post here usefully, but the crucial part is:

> *identifier-or-keyword*:
>    *identifier-start-character* *identifier-part-characters*<sub>opt</sub>
>
> *identifier-start-character*:
>   *letter-character*
>   _ (the underscore character U+005F)
>
> *identifier-part-characters*:
>   *identifier-part-character*
>   *identifier-part-characters* *identifier-part-character*
>
> *identifier-part-character*:
>   *letter-character*
>   *decimal-digit-character*
>   *connecting-character*
>   *combining-character*
>   *formatting-character*
>
> *letter-character*:
>   A Unicode character of classes Lu, Ll, Lt, Lm, Lo, or Nl
>   A unicode-escape-sequence representing a character of classes Lu, Ll, Lt, Lm, Lo, or Nl

Note that the example of `30d` is a great one for why it's not allowed - that's actually a numeric literal, of the value 30 and type `double`. (You've actually got `30dhi` of course, but the parser has parsed `30d` as a token.)

Comment: that dear that helped . i missed it :)